# How to catch an exception from the calling file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I have the following Javascript code

`main.js`

```
'use-strict';
const assert = require('assert');
var r = require('./index.js');
async function fun() {
    try {
    r.start();
} catch (e) {console.log(e);}
}
fun();
```

`index.js`

```
'use-strict';
var assert = require('assert');
async function start() {
   
    assert.ok(1==0);
}

exports.start = start;
```

Now the exception thrown in `index.js` is NOT caught in `main.js`, why so ? Is there any way I can facilitate this ?

I have a series of functions in different files invoked from main.js and I don't want to put try/catch in all of them.

Comment: Async Function call returns the promise so you can handle the error in the `catch` block of the promise.

Comment: @rogu-smith I am new to javascript, can you please elaborate with code reference  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change main.js to this, hopefully the error will be caught as the function will wait for the promise to resolve, and throw the error in main.js.

main.js

```
'use-strict'
const assert = require('assert')
const r = require('./index.js')
const fun = async () => {
  try {
    // Wait for the promise to resolve
    await r.start()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    throw new Error(`[main.js] - Error was thrown ${error}`)
  }
}
fun()
```

Comment: I modified my main.js to the mentioned one, but it doesn't seem to work, am I missing something ?

Comment: What happens? Do you get any erros?